# JavaScript array losing scope and not passing into my function

Tags: javascript, arrays, scope

I'm creating an array as a result of a TAFFYDB() query (but any array will do).

```
var ret=anaDataDB({"objID":"micro","objVal":1}).get();
console.log(ret.length);  // correctly shows 2
$("#submissionInput").fadeOut(function(){
  console.log(ret.length);  // correctly shows 2     
  $("#anaInputs").load("data/stubs/csaReport.html").promise().done(function(){
            console.log(ret.length);  // is undefined
```

I tried passing it in the function call

```
$("#submissionInput").fadeOut(function(){
    $("#anaInputs").load("data/stubs/csaReport.html").promise().done(function(ret){
        console.log(ret.length);  // shows 1 ??
```

I'm assuming this is because I used a promise or some other witchery. 
Why do I lose my scope?

Comment: `reg` and `ret` are different variables.

Comment: what is `reg`? replace it with `ret`

Comment: sorry, that was a typo. It's "ret" everywhere in my code

Comment: Does the array get mutated after the code you posted?

Comment: No. I had to manually retype some of the code for clarification and had a typo. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't need to pass it to the outer function first? Like so:

```
$("#submissionInput").fadeOut(function(ret){
    $("#anaInputs").load("data/stubs/csaReport.html").promise().done(function(ret){
        console.log(ret.length);  // shows 1 ??
```

Comment: console.log(ret.length);  correctly shows 2   after the outer function call

Comment: Sorry - you are correct. You are overloading ret. In other words, it is just the opposite. Remove the ret variable passing into the done method. e.g. $("#anaInputs").load("data/stubs/csaReport.html").promise().done(function(){